# How can I debug twitter bootstrap v4-alpha grid? col-sm-offset-* not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've changed something, somewhere and now `col-sm-offset-*`s aren't working at all. For example, if I wanted to split the screen in half, and display content only on the right hand side, I would usually use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
            This content isn't on the right hand side, it's on the left as if the col-sm-offset-6 isn't even there.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I check what's wrong?

I'm using NPM and Laravel Elixir (gulp) to minify (make production ready) the files and short of me copying the entire CSS file here, I don't know what else to do. Is there anything obvious? Has anyone come across this before?

#### Update

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
            <div class="row">
                <form role="form" method="POST" action="/register">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="abcdefghij">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="form-control-label">Username</label>
                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control " id="username" placeholder="Enter a username" value="j">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="first_name" class="form-control-label">First Name</label>
                            <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control " id="first_name" placeholder="Enter your first name" value="John">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="last_name" class="form-control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control " id="last_name" placeholder="Enter your last name" value="Appleseed">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="form-control-label">Email Address</label>
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control " id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" value="j@a.com">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="form-control-label">Password</label>
                            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control " id="password" placeholder="Enter a password" value="password">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="password_confirmation" class="form-control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input name="password_confirmation" type="password" class="form-control " id="password_confirmation" placeholder="Please confirm your password" value="password">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Web Inspector

[image: Web Inspector]

#### CSS Computed Properties

[image: CSS Computed Properties]

#### Update 2

I've submitted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19562) as this may have been intentional.

Comment: The markup [works fine](http://www.codeply.com/go/Q3oh7wMLuX). Hit F12 in the browser to see what classes are being applied to the inner div.

Comment: @Skelly I've updated my post. There aren't any other classes that have been added, and I've stripped back my SCSS files to the very basic v4-alpha-2 files that are pulled in through NPM. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: What happened when you inspected the offset div in the browser? You should see that bootstrap.css is being applied to it. The markup works so most likely there is something with how bootstrap is being included.

Comment: I've updated my question again with a couple of screenshots from the web inspector. There isn't anything added to the col-sm-offset-6 properties.

Comment: @Mike check the main bootstrap file and see if `col-sm-offset-6` is present.

Comment: Only sm-offset-6 is, without the col- prefix. :/

Comment: @Mike maybe something went wrong when compiling the .scss files to the final `bootstrap.css` file. Or maybe there is a bug in v4-alpha-2. I'd recommend you that you use the [dist files from bootstraps repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/dist) or [from it's homepage](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/).

Comment: It was working yesterday and I haven't touched the gulpfile so not sure what could have caused it. Just deleted the node_modules directory and re-downloaded the dependencies and still the same issue.

Comment: @Vucko I've created an issue on GitHub as I think this was intentional...

Comment: @Mike I've subscribed to your issue on github, it's interesting why it isn't working. I'd say that something went wrong when compiling the .scss files to the final bootstrap.css.

Comment: It looks like you're using the .css file directly from v4-dev/dist, which isn't really a stable v4-alpha. I would use the one from [MaxCDN](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.css). You can use directly from GitHub but it won't be stable. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/19099 confirms the intent to change `.offset`

Comment: @Skelly yeah I'd since found that out. I was using the SCSS version pulled in through NPM and compiling it through gulp.

Comment: Intentional? I know it's a work in progress but they [should mention this change in the docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/), because I believe that this will broke a lot of web pages.

Comment: I agree, and that is what all of the issues say yet they are all just closed and everyone is told to reference the docs from the last 'major' version, ie the untouched v4-alpha-2. So anything since then is undocumented, which is a shame as that means you can't use SASS/SCSS readily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub have officially changed their `col-bp-offset-*` names although the documentation is currently outdated.

See issues: [#19099](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/19099), [#19368](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19368), [#19267](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19267), and my own [#19562](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19562).

I'll close the question and update my GitHub issue too.

Answer (score 2):

The current correct offset class for Bootstrap v4 Alpha:

```
 class="col-md-6 offset-md-3"
```

Comment: Is it just me or is their [current documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns) showing offsets as having the same syntax as version 3? A bit frustrating!

Comment: Yeah the current v4 docs are off on a few things. I also just look at the source CSS file to find what I am looking for if what's in the docs isn't working.

Comment: When you wrote this answer, I immediately thought to myself why I hadn't done just that =.=